# Building search filter using ReactJs, and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

App is running on Node.js and React. In database (mongodb used) I have collection Rooms that contains details about particular room.

I am trying to search that collection based on for example number of guests and if number of guests in search input is 2 I would like to display all the rooms that can have two guests.

Also my question is is it possible to do search input for every field in collection rooms? For example number of guests, room type, price and so on...

Also is it better to do it with search input or dropdown search?

***SERVER PART***

**UserModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Define our model
const roomSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    price: { type: Number },
    room_type: { type: String },
    nb_guests: { type: Number },
    imageData: {type: String}
});

// Create the model class
const ModelClass = mongoose.model('room', roomSchema);

// Export the model
module.exports = ModelClass;
```

***CLIENT PART***

**LandingPage.js**

```
const Room = props => (
    <div className = "col-md-4" >
        <div className="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <img src={room9} class="card-img-top" 
             alt="..." width="100%" height="225" />
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{props.room.title}</h5>
                <p className="card-text">{props.room.description}</p>
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align- 
                       items-center">
                    <div className="btn-group">
                    <Link  className="btn btn-sm 
                    btn-outline-secondary" to={"/view/"+props.room._id}>View</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div >
)

function searchingFor(term){
    return function(x){
        return x.props.room.nb_guests.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || !term;
    }
}
    export default class LandingPage extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { 
                rooms: [],
                term:''
            }
            this.onSearchHandler = this.onSearchHandler.bind(this);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            axios.get('http://localhost:3090/admin/')
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({
                        rooms: response.data
                    })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        })
                })
        }

        roomList() {
            return this.state.rooms.filter(searchingFor(this.state.term)).map(function (currentRoom, i) {
                return <Room room={currentRoom} key={i} />
            });
        }

        onSearchHandler(e){
            this.setState({
                term:e.target.value
            })
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <LPheader />
                    <Carousel />
                    <div>
                        <div className="album py-5 bg-light">
                            <div className="container">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <form>
                                        <input 
                                        type="text"
                                        onChange={this.onSearchHandler}
                                        value={term}
                                        />
                                    </form>
                                    {this.roomList()}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

This is the code I started with and I am getting this error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: term is not defined`

To be completely honest I am not even sure if this is right way to do it,
any advice would be highly appreciated.

**Update**

```
roomList = () => {
        const { rooms, term } = this.state;

        if (!term) {
          return rooms.map(function(currentRoom, i) {
            return <Room room={currentRoom} key={i} />;
          });
        } else if {
          return rooms
            .filter(room => {
              return room.nb_guests == term;
            })
            .map(matchingRoom => {
              return <Room room={matchingRoom} />;
            });
            else if{
                .filter(room => {
                    return room.price == term;
                  })
                  .map(matchingRoom => {
                    return <Room room={matchingRoom} />;
                  });
                  else if{
                    .filter(room => {
                        return room.room_type == term;
                      })
                      .map(matchingRoom => {
                        return <Room room={matchingRoom} />;
                      });
            }
        }
      };

      onSearchHandlerPrice = e => {
        this.setState({
          term: (e.target.value)
        });
      };

      onSearchHandlerGuests = e => {
        this.setState({
          term: (e.target.value)
        });
      };


<div className="container">
<div className="row">
  <form>
    <input type="text" onChange={this.onSearchHandlerGuests} value={this.state.term} />
  </form>

  <form>
    <input type="text" onChange={this.onSearchHandlerPrice} value={this.state.term} />
  </form>
  {this.roomList()}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your `render` method, on your `form` tag change ` value={term}` to ` value={this.state.term}`

Comment: I changed it thanks! I don't know how I missed it. But now it can't recognize `room` I think it's issue with my `function searchingFor()` because it is outside of class component or what do you think?

Comment: Are you just using React and Node? Any redux?

Comment: Yes. Not in this component bu I am using it

Comment: Gotcha, was just wondering because it seems like you're front-loading all the data inside your Landing page component. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close to getting this done. I think the `searchingFor()` function is over-complicating your logic. See the following sandbox on how you can filter the rooms by number of guests: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-dan-vjt7o

**Notes**:

- I commented out the `axios` request and just plugged in some sample
  data. It should still work if you swap it back with your own code.

You could simplify your code by updating the `term` state-value as the user types, causing a re-render and inside the newly executed `roomList()`, filter and return the appropriate rooms that match `term`.

```
  roomList = () => {
    const { rooms, term } = this.state;

    if (!term) {
      return rooms.map(function(currentRoom, i) {
        return <Room room={currentRoom} key={i} />;
      });
    } else {
      return rooms
        .filter(room => {
          return room.nb_guests == term;
        })
        .map(matchingRoom => {
          return <Room room={matchingRoom} />;
        });
    }
  };

  onSearchHandler = e => {
    this.setState({
      term: e.target.value
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your code! It's working but when I enter in search bar number 2 it displays correctly rooms with two guests but when I try delete that number and put other in search input I can't and error that I am getting is ' Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.' and `Received NaN for the value attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.` Do you maybe know why?

Comment: @user9347049 ahh yes, thats happening because of the `parseFloat()`. In `onSearchHandler()`, just get rid of the `parseFloat` so it will look like `term: e.target.value` and then in the `.filter()` use double equals ==, so `return room.nb_guests == term`  Also see updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-dan-vjt7o

Comment: Thank you it really did the trick! May I have one more question as I am trying to solve it by myself but also kinda stuck :/ for example if I would like to do search also for other fields in room collection how would I change `roomList()` function. For example one search input for number of guests other for price then for room type and so on.. I have put some code in my question update like idea of how to do it can you please check

Comment: @user9347049 sure! It all depends how you want the user to be able to search. You could break this up into multiple inputs if you'd like. You could have an input for each field and update the term with the data provided by the focused input. Additionally, we would just need another field in our state to keep track of what criteria to search for. I'll try to give you an example in a code solution.

Comment: @user9347049 See sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-dan-vjt7o This would be the general idea on how you can customize your search depending on the input the user enters. Try to build upon this logic by creating filters for room-type, title and etc :)

Comment: It's working as it should but I am getting this error `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` do you know why? Although is working correctly and this is what I was looking for :)

Comment: @user9347049 oh yeah, that just happens because I forgot to give a key to each Room component in the` roomList()` else block... Just do:         `.map((matchingRoom, i) => {
          return <Room room={matchingRoom} key={i} />;
        });`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your detailed answers and effort :) I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @user9347049 you're very welcome! I hope you found this helpful